# c++ use a vector define in one source file in another source file

Tags: c++

If I define a vector e.g. `vector<int> vect{ 10, 20, 30 };`  in a source `.cpp` file and I want to pass it to a function in another source file e.g. `function(vect)`, is the only way to do this to create a header file and make the vector `extern` and include this header file in both source files.

Is there anyway to do this without a header?

Comment: You can declare it (`extern`) in whatever source files you would need to use such a variable, without the use of a header. `#include` is just a copy-paste.

Comment: Is `function` visible to the file `vect` is defined in?

Comment: Probably a lot of different ways to achieve whatever you would like to achieve. But you need to describe your problem in a more precise way. Why exactly do you need to do? Share 3 integer values between your compilation units?

Comment: There is certainly **no** need to make the vector object "`extern`"! In fact, most likely it should live inside a function and it should be impossible to make it `extern`. The vector *type* just needs to be known. Note that header files are just a tool to make declarations available: there is no need to use them. You can just write the declaration where it is needed. In general that's not done because instead of having one central place for the declaration there are many places which need to be located and potentially updated. ... and some project *policies* prohibit local declarations.

Comment: If a compilation unit (aka source file) has visibility of declarations of both the vector `vect` and the function, it is possible to pass `vect` as an argument to the function.   Of course, that assumes one of the functions arguments can be used to pass `vect` to the function.

Comment: @ariane cathal Is there a reason you want to avoid using a header file?

Comment: Of course, it is rather difficult to define a variable of type `std::vector<int>` without `#include <vector>` in at least one compilation unit.  `<vector>` identifies a standard header.

Answer (score 4):

If you pass the vector as a parameter (`function(vect)` as you said) then you do **not** need to make the vector `extern` and put it in a header file.

All you need is to prototype the function, e.g.

```
void function(vector<int>& vect);
```

and put that in a header file. Include that header file in both the file that defines `function` and the file that calls `function` and you're done.

You could do this without a header file (but why?) just put the prototype in the file that calls the function. That's an inferior solution however. Why do you want to avoid a header file?

Comment: The question is `Is there anyway to do this without a header?` ;)

Comment: @Korni I've addressed that (as far as I can).

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need a header file for declaration of the `vect` object. As long as the declaration of `function` is available, either directly  or through a header file, you can use `vect` in the call to `function`.